# ZeroClipboard / zClip -- how to bind to live events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I'm trying to bind zclip with live:

```
$('.code').live('click', function () {
    $(this).zclip({
        path: '<%= asset_path "ZeroClipboard.swf" %>',
        copy: $(this).text()
    });

    ...
});
```

It doesn't seem to work that way. **Any clues?**

I need to do live because some DOM elements are added with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can put zclip-binding into the callback function in your ajax method, like this:

```
$.post('ajax',
   {data:"data"}, 
       function(data){
      //add dom elements
      ....
          //bind zclip
          $('.code').each(function(){
    $(this).zclip({
      path:".ZeroClipboard.swf",
      copy:$(this).txt()
        });
      });
   }, 'json');
```

each() is to avoid $('.code') have two or more elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of jQuery that you're using.
You should be using .delegate() or .on()(if jQuery >= 1.7) instead anyways. (jQuery deprecated the .live method)
They should work with your newly added elements via ajax.

```
$('.code').on('click', function () {
    $(this).zclip({
        path: '<%= asset_path "ZeroClipboard.swf" %>',
        copy: $(this).text()
    });
});
```